# Angular CORS in Amazon S3 (without a server)

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I want to know if is possible to run an AngularJS app directly from Amazon S3 bucket, having in mind that this app makes requests to a web server.

This will generate a CORS problem, considering that the files on S3 are not running on a HTTP server?

If more information is needed so that you can help me, I can readily answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its possible I currently have a couple of websites there, check this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance S3 is the HTTP server. You wouldn't be able to load the site in the browser if there was no server serving the files.

The CORS issue will depend on the CORS configuration on the web server hosting the resources AngularJS will be requesting.